# Laravel cron job not running automatically

Tags: php, laravel

I've setup a scheduled job for my project and it works fine if i run the command php artisan schedule:run but i'm not sure how to make it automated.

Answer (score 2):

If you [read the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler), you will see that it tell's you 100% what to do to achieve what you need...

So, you have to edit your `crontab` and add:

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I've cd to my project path then ran the command. I got this error: 
out-file : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\dev\null'.
At line:1 char:1
+ php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

Comment: Are you running this on windows ? Then I have no idea, this is for Linux...

Comment: Yeah im running this on windows. that's okay thanks for the help

Comment: What are you using on windows ? `cron` only exists linux systems... I think if you use WSL or WSL2 it should still work because it is linux

Comment: I'm not sure if im getting the idea right. I added the php file and added the scheduler line in the kernel.php. Then i uploaded the files to the website that hosts the site. it's not running in the website. The server hosting the website is called plesk

Comment: You have to be running a `linux` environment to use `crontabs/cron`. I have no idea if `Plesk` is running under a `linux` environment and if you have access to edit `cron` or you have `SSH` access to edit it.